# grabbing variables from database in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to add create a product page and I have all the relevant column names in the product table but the loop won't work for some reason :(

```
<?php
 $dbhost = 'localhost';
 $dbuser = 'CU4507408';
 $dbpass = '*********';
 $dbname = 'CU4507408';
 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to database");
 mysql_select_db($dbname);
 $query  = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['productID'].";";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("failed!");
 while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $productID = $row['productID'];
       $name = $row['name'];
       $price = $row['price'];
       $manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
       $rating = $row['rating'];
       $categoryID = $row['categoryID'];
       $productinfo = $row['productinfo'];
       $image = $row['image'];
       $youtube = $row['youtube'];
 }
?>
```

There error I get is

```
Undefined index: productID in /home/4507408/public_html/viewproduct.php on line 8 failed!
```

productID is the primary key of the product table

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like `$_REQUEST['productID']` is not set

Comment: Please use the `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions, since `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You're doing `mysql_query`, but then you do `$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.  You can't just mix-and-match `mysql_` and `PDO` code like that.  You need to use the correct functions for the correct API.

Comment: +1 @kingkero, you may use, var_dump or print_r functions in while loop to see everything in your $row for debugging. ie while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ print_r($row) }

Comment: Also, ***PLEASE*** do not actually use this code.  It's unsafe.  What if I request a `productID` of `''; DROP TABLE product; --`?  It's 2014, you should be upgrading to PDO or MySQLi and using prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for your respone guys, I don't have a clue why they are teaching us on old MySQL at uni, im looking at all these guides and stuff and it appears what we are using is stupidly old on there server.

Would anyone be able to help me on skype?

Comment: @Adam91Holt see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#13944958) e.g.

Comment: @Adam91Holt: Don't ask people if they are "able to help [you] on skype". That's not how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_REQUEST['productID']` is undefined.

Your URL (if you're using GET), should look like this:

```
www.example.com/products?productID=3
```

If the `productID` part is missing, it becomes undefined.